# Pandas - Vectorize / Improve performance of fillna(), ffill(), bfill()

Tags: python, pandas

Noticed that Pandas fillna() and similar operations are quite slow on large datasets - (currently batch processing 250~ million rows).

Particularly interested in rolling().{some function}.fillna()

Is there a way to vectorize/ or improve performance on these functions?

Comment: Do you have to apply `fillna()` as part of `rolling()`?  Could you instead fill NaNs after rolling is complete?  e.g. `df.loc[df.col1.isnull(),'col1'] = fill_value`

Comment: Provide some example data with working code and you are likely to get many more responses. Even a basic calculation with 10 rows to demonstrate the issue is useful. As it stands, we don't have anything to benchmark.

Comment: @NicBraunagel usually I do something like rolling().std().fillna(), There does not seem to be performance improvements by rolling().std() and fillna() separtely